# Table tool in showing one fewer database records

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i'm using table tool of jasper report but when i run this using ireport, it's showing one less record for every SQl query! if any1 has used it and faced same problem then please show me a way!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Table tool in showing one fewer database records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046838/table-tool-in-showing-one-fewer-database-records)