# Table tool in showing one fewer database records

Tags: database, jasper-reports, ireport

the main concern is my query is running smoothly in SQL and also in table dataset query preview. i mean in table dataset query data preview it's displaying 2 records from my database table.

please find the screen shot[image].

also find Jrxml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report2" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Table Dataset 1">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select lname, fname from test1
order by fname]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="lname" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="fname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="New Dataset 1">
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[select lname, fname from test1
order by fname]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="lname" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="fname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select lname, fname from test1
order by fname]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="lname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="41" width="102" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[lname]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="202" y="41" width="147" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[fname]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table" style="table" x="100" y="0" width="360" height="86"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Table Dataset 1">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="90">
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{lname}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90">
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{fname}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

but the output in pdf report is only 1 record which is last 1.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is happening to me when using a JRBeanCollectionDataSource. I know for a fact that all the data is there but the table tool keeps missing the first row.
It looks like the main report executes a ".next()" on the collection or something then the subreport (a.k.a table) keeps on going with the rest of the data

Anyway, I solved it passing **$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.cloneDataSource()** as the dataSource expression of the table. Then it looks like the table starts with a brand new datasource and can iterate through all the items, and so, it works.
I don't know what datasource you are using but you have to figure out a way to move the cursor to the beginning of your data before using the subreport.

So, summing up, I did this in my jrxml file:
    `<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.cloneDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>`

but Only because I am using a [JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html#cloneDataSource%28%29)

Comment: cloneDataSource Works for me in terms of displaying all the rows in the table, but somehow, the table itself is being painted as many times as the number of rows!!!

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same problem as kawda and exactly the same behavior than user1972796 : multiple tables instead of one, but correct number of rows in one table.

The problem seams to appear in cases where the master report doesn't iterate over anything and the subreport has been put into the Details Band and references the master data source via $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}

The explanation (and solution) seams to be this one: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/why-first-record-missing-my-subreport

Comment: Can you add the relevant text/codeblocks of that link directly in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `<connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>`instead `<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>`